# How to save the elastocsearch database?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

In my work, I do several simulations so every time I use Kibana with elasticsearch to analyze my results.
So, I need to save my elasticsearch database every time in order to reuse it again.

How can do I do this please?

Comment: You want to create a backup so to speak?

Comment: @Fariha what do you mean by `database` here? IMO, there is no such word used in elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My log file is parsed and filtered according to my filters in the config file of logstash and then the data will be saved in elasticsearch. 
In my work I have several log files to analyze so I run several times the procedure and every time when I want to view the data stored before I can not find them. Each time in kibana I can view only the new parsed data of the new log. So I need to store my data each time in order to reuse them later.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your document ids are setup such that they aren't time based and so they are being overwritten on each run. Without knowing the details of you configuration file, it's hard to say more.